# Pixels of Thin Chars are not of the Exact Requested Color

Tags: html, html5-canvas

To recover character bounding boxes I draw the full HTML onto HTML canvas in different colors so I can locate them by their pixel color values. Not all pixel colors are those that I assigned to the character, but most are e.g. majority of the pixels of an 'a' drawn with font color rgb(0,0,100) have the color rgb(0,0,100).

However, for pixels of some thin chars such as '-' or '2' of the exponent, the colors are none of those assigned. If I assigned (0,20,71) as the font color, majority of the pixels color values are NOT (0,20,71) but instead (66,81,119). Due to these alternate colors, when I go looking for pixels with color (0,20,71) I find none, and end up without a bounding box for '-' etc.

1. Are there color choices that minimize use of alternate colors to display a character? If yes then perhaps I could use those colors instead of random color values.
2. Is there an HTML rendering attribute that I could turn on/off to minimize the use of alternate colors?
3. Or is there perhaps a simpler way of doing all this? I used to draw those characters one after another, which worked better, but was too slow to be useful.

Note that I don't need the bounding boxes that could be recovered using the font information or getBoundingClientRect as they are not always exact.

Note: This question is cross posted from graphicdesign as it is more appropriate for this forum.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes. Right. Will add. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by **anti-aliasing** of the text. To get a better understanding, let's have a look at
this highly magnified 'a' character in red color (#ff000) as it would be rendered on the canvas.
[image]

As you can see the main shape is indeed painted in red color but it's surrounded by lighter tones of red. If we
simply look for a fixed color (e.g. #ff0000) the selection wouldn't contain the surrounding pixels, as it's a
blend between the foreground and the background color - e.g. #ffbfc1 (pink). So if we go further and try to obtain a bounding-box based on red, it would look like this:

[image]

One possible fix goes a bit like this:

- get the canvas pixel data
- check each pixels color - if it's something different than fully transparent, replace it with a fully opaque solid black #000000
- write the pixel data back to the canvas

For the 'a' above this will give us something like this:

[image]

Now we can simply go over the pixel data once more, look for black pixels and figure out the min/max x and y values to obtain the surrounding area.

[image]

Here's a complete code example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '12px Arial';
ctx.fillText('a²+b²=c²', 110, 90);
ctx2.font = '12px Arial';
ctx2.fillText('a²+b²=c²', 110, 90);

let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
let color;
for (let a = 0; a < imageData.data.length; a += 4) {
  color = imageData.data[a] * imageData.data[a + 1] + imageData.data[a + 2] + imageData.data[a + 3];
  if (color > 0) {
    imageData.data[a] = 0;
    imageData.data[a + 1] = 0;
    imageData.data[a + 2] = 0;
    imageData.data[a + 3] = 255;
  }
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let minY = canvas.height;
let maxY = 0;
let minX = canvas.width;
let maxX = 0;
for (let a = 0; a < imageData.data.length; a += 4) {
  if (imageData.data[a + 3] == 255) {
    y = Math.floor((a / 4) / canvas.width);

    x = (a / 4) - (y * canvas.width);
    if (y < minY + 1) {
      minY = y - 1;
    }
    if (y > maxY - 1) {
      maxY = y + 1;
    }
    if (x < minX + 1) {
      minX = x - 1;
    }
    if (x > maxX - 1) {
      maxX = x + 1;
    }
  }
}

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.strokeRect(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
```

```html
<div style="display:block;"><canvas id="canvas2" style="background-color:grey;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:grey;"></canvas></div>
```